# SQL Server 2012: Login to PC-NAME\SQLEXPRESS works, but not to local/(local)

Tags: sql-server, database-connection, connection-string, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2012-express

I'd like to login to my SQL Server 2012 Express with servername `local` or `(local)` but it doesn't work.

The only servername which works is `PC-Name\SQLEXPRESS`.

`local/(local)` has to work somehow because I have to use the following connection string:

```
Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=...
```

Comment: Have you tried "localhost\SQLEXPRESS"?

Comment: Or .\SQLEXPRESS? to get the name local to work you will have to either add it into DNS as a CNAME pointing to your machine (bad idea as that will be confusing for other machines as they will also be able to resolve local to your machine), or to your hosts file pointing to 127.0.0.1, otherwise how will your computer know what local is?

Comment: Yep, that works. Thanks.
I think this is because I have unfortunatley selected to use a named instance instead of the default instance ... 
I'm thinking to outsource the connection string to the local computer level. Maybe this would be the best. So we wouldn't have to care about the name of an instance anymore ...

Comment: @steolary: `local` has special meaning for the SQL drivers. Is a valid name for localhost w/o any additional tricks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've reinstalled it and ensures to select "default instance" instead of "named instance" during the installation. Now everything is fine again.

Answer (score 1):

I think I see what you're trying to do now.

If you really don't like using the hostname\instance combination and you are using the SQL native client to connect, you can always add an alias in the native client called local that resolves to your instance.  That way you can keep your connection string in your application the same no matter what server/instance you end up sticking the application on just by changing the alias.

See the link below for details on how to configure:

[How to setup and use a SQL Server alias](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1620/how-to-setup-and-use-a-sql-server-alias/)

Comment: Nope, good idea, but still not working. :(
Think I have to reinstall ... Too bad this takes so much time.