# Connect to SQL Server 2012 Database with C# (Visual Studio 2012)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Evening all,

I'm trying to connect to a SQL Server 2012 database from C#. My connection settings when using SQL Server Management Studio are as below:-

```
Server Type:    Database Engine
Server Name:    Paul-PC\SQLEXPRESS
Authentication: Windows Authentication
Username:   Greyed out
Password:   Greyed out
```

The name of the database I'm trying to connect to is "testDB".

Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace DatabaseConnection
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("server=localhost;" +
                                       "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
                                       "database=testDB; " +
                                       "connection timeout=30");
            try
            {
                myConnection.Open();
                MessageBox.Show("Well done!");
            }
            catch(SqlException ex)
            {
               MessageBox.Show("You failed!" + ex.Message);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, my code fails to connect with the following error:-

"You failed!A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections."

Any suggestions? SQL Server is running locally.

Comment: Make sure your SQL server service is running behind

Comment: 1. Does it do the same error if you do `(local)` instead of `localhost` for the server? 2. Can you open the server in Sql Server Management Studio?

Comment: @Shaharyar what do you mean by this? I have checked services.msc and SQL Server is running.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Yes I can access it through Management Studio and I'm actually logged in when I run the code. I tried changing 'localhost' to 'local' but to no avail

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449607/point-to-localhost-sqlexpress-using-only-localhost and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15023131/sql-server-2012-login-to-pc-name-sqlexpress-works-but-not-to-local-local

Comment: What happens if you use `server=(local)\\SQLEXPRESS`? also are you 100% sure you are working on `Paul-PC`?

Comment: @Chris Thanks for the links. I've enabled TCP/IP but still no joy.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Excellent. "server=(local)\\SQLEXPRESS" solved the problem. Thanks

Comment: @thefragileomen If your questions has been answered then consider marking one of the answers as accepted.

Answer (score 6):

In your connection string replace `server=localhost`  with "`server = Paul-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;`"

Answer (score 3):

I tested all the answers here, but for me, none worked. So I studied a bit the problem, and finally I found the connection string needed. To get this string, you do:
1. in you project name:
   a. right click the project name,
   b. click Add,
   c. select SQL Server Database (obviously you can rename it as you wish).
   Now the new desired database will be added to your project.
2. The database is visible in the Server Explorer window.
3. Left click the database name in the Server Explorer window; now check the Solution Explorer    window, and you will find the "Connection String", along side with Provider, State, Type, Version.
4. Copy the connection string provided, and put it in the Page_Load method:

```
string source = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=c:\x\x\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\WebApplication3\WebApplication3\App_Data\Product.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(source);
conn.Open();
//your code here;
conn.Close();
```

I renamed my database as Product. Also, in the "AttachDbFilename", you must replace "c:\x\x\documents\" with your path to the phisical address of the .mdf file.

It worked for me, but I must mention this method works for VS2012 and VS2013. Don't know about other versions.

Comment: It only worked in Visual Studio 3013 Community.While copying connection string from properties dont forget to REMOVE the double quotes after AttachDbFilename that points to the mdf file. If you put that in conn string you will get exception

Answer (score 0):

Replacing `server=localhost` with `server=.\SQLEXPRESS` might do the job.

Comment: Thanks Dennis. I tried this but it Visual Studio returned an error when trying to compile - "unrecognised escape sequent". I therefore tried a double backslash but code still doesn't work.

Comment: the escape sequence thing is because of the single "/", if you're a beginner this website will be a very good reference to different connection strings for any DBMS : http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Database=testDB;Server=Paul-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True;connect timeout = 30");
```

Answer (score 0):

Note to under

```
connetionString =@"server=XXX;Trusted_Connection=yes;database=yourDB;";
```

Note: XXX = . OR .\SQLEXPRESS  OR .\MSSQLSERVER OR (local)\SQLEXPRESS OR (localdb)\v11.0 &...

you can replace '**server**' with '**Data Source**'

too you can replace '**database**' with '**Initial Catalog**'

Sample:

```
 connetionString =@"server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Trusted_Connection=yes;Initial Catalog=books;";
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider including some information about your answer, rather than simply posting code. We try to provide not just 'fixes', but help people learn. You should explain what was wrong in the original code, what you did differently, and why your change(s) worked.

Answer (score -1):

use this style

```
@"server=.\sqlexpress;"
```

Comment: this is not the correct way to answer,do answer in some detailed way.and do read FAQ to use stackoverflow in a proper way.

Comment: You also may have noticed that pretty much this exact answer was posted [5 months ago](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17265115/237838)