# Is there any difference between SQL Sever Compact Edition and SQL Server Express Edition?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

I have created a database for Windows Form Application in SQL Server Express Edition 2012. Can I install SQL Server Compact Edition at client side to use this database for my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to connect to SQL Server Expess Edition, [you can use SqlClient to connect with your Windows Form Application.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17265068/connect-to-sql-server-2012-database-with-c-sharp-visual-studio-2012)

It's not possible to use Compact Edition to connect regular SQL Server unless you re-create your database on the Compact Edition because it connects to a locally accessible file.

SQL Server CE is like SQLite, which does not require an installation of an instance. (Only a runtime dll will be sufficent.) It will reside on your application's memory.

On the otherhand, SQL Server Express Edition is a full DBMS (Database management system) which stays on the system as a server. Express Edition only implies reduced functionality (like memory limit)